# C# keep DataTable in Sync with Database

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I'm writing a read-only front end for a database and can't seem to find a way to keep the data in sync.
I can query the database and put the results into a DataTable and then attach that to a DataSet and use that as the DataSource for a DataGridView, what i am struggling with is refreshing the rows in the DataTable/DataSet and the changes being reflected in the DataGridView.

```
    DataTable orders = new DataTable();
    DataTable lines = new DataTable();
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    private string orderQuery = "SELECT oh_ord_no AS OrderID, oh_stat AS OrderStatus, oh_cu_no AS CustomerID, cus_name AS CustomerName, cus_price_no AS PriceBand, cus_ac_manager AS AccountManager, oh_ord_type AS OrderType, oh_ord_ref AS OrderReference, oh_del_meth AS DeliveryMethod, oh_op_no AS InputBy, oh_route_no AS Route, CAST(SQL_DATE,DATEADD(day,-1,oh_ord_date)) AS OrderDate, CAST(SQL_DATE,DATEADD(day,-1,oh_del_date)) AS DeliveryDate, oh_head_text AS HeaderText, oh_foot_text AS FooterText, oh_total_units AS TotalUnits, oh_ord_value AS OrderValue, CAST(SQL_DATE,DATEADD(day,oh_status_change_date,'1899-12-31')) AS StatusChangeDate, oh_status_change_time AS StatusChangeTime, oh_conf_no FROM admin.sffoh1 LEFT JOIN admin.sdfcus ON oh_cu_no = cus_no";
    private string orderLines = "SELECT ilf_ord_no AS OrderID, ilf_prod_ptr AS ProductID FROM admin.sffilf";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orders = SwordsData.GetData(orderQuery, "orders");
        orders.AcceptChanges();
        lines = SwordsData.GetData(orderLines, "lines");
        dataSet.Tables.Add(orders);
        dataSet.Tables.Add(lines);
        dataview.DataSource = dataSet;
        dataview.DataMember = "orders";
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orders.Reset();
        orders = SwordsData.GetData(orderQuery, "orders");
        lines = SwordsData.GetData(orderLines, "lines");
        dataSet.GetChanges();
    }
```

That is what i have so far.  I just can't seem to find anything online to help me :(

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated.
Lee.

Comment: Why you want to do that? It's really the path of evil. Query the database directly.

Comment: Drop the `DataSet` and use `BindingSources` as datasource for the DGV. Couple the `BindingSource` to your `DataTable` and then changes will be updated in your DGV automatic

Comment: @GuidoG That worked a treat, many thanks.